# Why my NSPopover doesn't become first responder?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nspopover

I'm programming in macOS project.

In my project, there is a tableview. When clicking on a tableview cell, a popover will show.

But I find that after showing the popover, the window's `firstResponder` is still my tableview. What's more, when I explicitly call :

```
 window?.makeFirstResponder(popover) //window is not nil.
```

The popover will became first responder after this line of code but almost immediately resign first responder. And the tableview becomes first responder again.

[image]

I just want to close popover when it resign first responder, but I don't know why it cannot become first responder when it shows.

--

**EDIT**

Code for creating popover:

```
//In tablecellview's subview
let popover = NSPopover()

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    ...

    let controller = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "popover") as! ColorSelectionPopoverVC
    controller.selectionDelegate = self
    popover.contentViewController = controller
}

override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    if !disablePopover && !popover.isShown {
        popover.show(relativeTo: self.bounds, of: self, preferredEdge: .maxX)            
    }
// The following line can let popover'contentVC become first responder for a while. 
//        window?.makeFirstResponder(popover.contentViewController)

    super.mouseDown(with: event)

}
```

Comment: `UITableView` on OS X?

Comment: @Willeke NSTableView, thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the table view doesn't want to resign first responder or the table view is made first responder again. Do you make the table view or a cell first responder somewhere in your code?

Comment: @Willeke No, I don't explicitly do that. There is a gesture recognizer in my popover. Even when I trigger that gesture in my popover, the first responder is still the tableview.

Comment: How did you create the pop-over?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I have edited the question . Thank you.

Comment: Just a Q: Why do you want to make the popover the first responder? Does it have a text input or dos it react on action messages?

Comment: Because I want to close it when I click anywhere else. And I can do this when it resigns first responder if it can become first responder.@AminNegm-Awad

Comment: Don't create the popover, instead present the view controller as popover.

Comment: @Willeke Thank you. I have tried and it works well so far.